# ZXing Library on storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, zxing

First of all I am new to IOS and trying to use ZXing library on one of my projects but I am using storyboard and auto memory management. So I am having hard time to convert the sample test code that comes with the library source code.

I have done the steps to include library to my project but I don't really know how to use the library. I tried to convert the sample code that comes with library but it is without auto memory management and also without storyboard. I am not familiar with .xib files so converting didn't really worked well. Is there any place that I can find sample code working on auto memory management and storyboard? Or if someone can help me to convert it would be great. I am trying to do this for two days but still at same point.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I found a better and so much easier to implement barcode and QR code scanning library called ZBar check it out http://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html :)